# Morse height function for general compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Can you give me the form of the height function for any compact manifold embedded in the reals?

Maybe the projection of the parametrization onto a basis vector ex.

For the n-sphere is $h(p)=\pi(\phi(p))=x_{n+1}$.

thanks

Comment: by "embedded in the reals" you mean the manifold is embedded in the *real vector space* $\Bbb R^n$ for suitable $n$, right?

Comment: right, in $ R^{2n}$ for n-mfld (Whitney)

Comment: Well, first you have to decide which coordinate you consider to be "height" - say it is $x_k$.  Then the height function is the composition of the function $(x_1, \ldots, x_N) \mapsto x_k$ with the embedding $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: by the way is the height fcn smooth?

Comment: I want to show that any height function is morse or close to one and I already have that morse are dense in smooth.

Comment: also, can we find those embeddings explicitly? If not would coordinate charts work?

Comment: The height functions are smooth since $\phi$ is smooth.  As for the rest, now your asking more questions!  Perhaps you should post them as such!

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi:M \to \Bbb R^n$ is in fact an isometric embedding, then the image $\text{Im} \phi$ of $M$ under $\phi$ is compact, since $M$ is compact.  If the $x_i$, $1 \le i \le n$, are a set of Cartesian coordinates on $\Bbb R^n$ (where by "Cartesian" I mean compatible with the vector space structure on $\Bbb R^n$, so they are related by a nonsingular linear transformation to the coordinates of the standard basis), the the $n$ functions $x_i \circ \phi$, being continuous (even differentiable!) functions on the compact set $M$, each attain a  minimum $m_i$ and maximum $M_i$ in $M$.  If we consider the hyperplane $x_i = m_i$ in $\Bbb R^n$, then for $p \in M$, $x_i \circ \phi(p) - m_i$ is the height of the point $\phi(p)$ above this hyperplane.  It is correct to assert the height functions associated with a given Cartisian coordinate system in $\Bbb R^n$ are given by the projections onto the coordinate axes, offset by the positions or "heights", relative to $0$, of the hyperplanes themselves.  In fact, one needn't restrict oneself to the the offsets being the $m_i$, though the hyperplanes $x_i = m_i$ have the nice feature that $\phi(M)$ "sits" right on them!  Taking any hyperplane $x_i = a_i$ yields a height function $x_i \circ \phi - a_i$ relative to *it*.  One can of course even generalize to the case of an arbitrary hyperplane $H$ given by an equation of the form $\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r = a$, where $\mathbf n$ is the unit normal vector to $H$ and $a$ is the distance 'twixt $H$ and $0 \in \Bbb R^n$; then $\mathbf n \cdot \phi(p) - a$ is the height of $\phi(p)$ relative to $H$; since $p \in M$, $\mathbf n \cdot \phi - a$ is a function on $M$ itself.

It should be observed however that such height functions won't *necessarily* be Morse functions in the sense of having non-singular Hessians at their critical points, etc.  *That* depends on the specifics of $M$ and $\phi$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and of course,

***Fiat Lux!!!***